# How to overload * argument unpacking operator?

Tags: python, arguments, argument-unpacking

I have data like `data = [[t1, t2, ...], [v1, v2, ...]]`. I want to wrap this in a class so I can call `data.t` instead of having to use `data[0]`.

I tried to do this with the following:

```
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.t = data[0]
        self.v = data[1]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return self.t
        elif key == 1:
            return self.v
        else:
            raise ValueError("not valid key '{}'".format(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == 0:
            self.t = value
        elif key == 1:
            self.v = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("not valid key '{}'".format(key))
```

The reason for the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` overloading is for backwards compability so that `data[0]` still works. This works for most things, however I run into problems with the following call:

```
func_that_takes_two_arguments(*data) # unpacking data
```

The error I get is

```
/Users/pingul/Workspace/lhcfill/oml.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     52                                 return self.val
     53                         else:
---> 54                                 raise ValueError("not valid key     '{}'".format(key))
     55 
     56                 def __setitem__(self, key, value):
ValueError: not valid key '2'
```

How can I make my class work properly with the argument unpacking operator?

Comment: You're not overloading `*`, that just iterates over the object. You need to `raise IndexError`, not `ValueError`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `*` operator works by iterating over the object. This iteration can well be performed with only implementing `__getitem__()`, but your implementation is faulty. Instead if raising `ValueError`, you should throw `IndexError` which signals the end of the iteration.

See also [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) which explicitly states

> **Note:** `for` loops expect that an `IndexError` will be raised for illegal indexes to allow proper detection of the end of the sequence.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter states that this is called the "sequence protocol".